# How to search in an id tree in the python program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a student and working on a small assignment where I need to collect inputs from the student on factors like kind of books they like to issue from the library. I've been provided id_tree class which I need to search using. As you can see I'm getting inputs from the console and I like to use that as the search criteria and get the recommendation from the id tree.

Just for testing purpose, I'm using out.py, but that needs to be replaced with id_tree search logic for which I'm struggling.

```
# k-Nearest Neighbors and Identification Trees
#api.py

import os
from copy import deepcopy
from functools import reduce

################################################################################
############################# IDENTIFICATION TREES #############################
################################################################################

class Classifier :
    def __init__(self, name, classify_fn) :
        self.name = str(name)
        self._classify_fn = classify_fn

    def classify(self, point):
        try:
            return self._classify_fn(point)
        except KeyError as key:
            raise ClassifierError("point has no attribute " + str(key) + ": " + str(point))

    def copy(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.name == other.name
                    and self._classify_fn.__code__.co_code == other._classify_fn.__code__.co_code)
        except:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return "Classifier<" + str(self.name) + ">"

    __repr__ = __str__


## HELPER FUNCTIONS FOR CREATING CLASSIFIERS

def maybe_number(x) :
    try :
        return float(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) :
        return x

def feature_test(key) :
    return Classifier(key, lambda pt : maybe_number(pt[key]))

def threshold_test(feature, threshold) :
    return Classifier(feature + " > " + str(threshold),
                      lambda pt: "Yes" if (maybe_number(pt.get(feature)) > threshold) else "No")


## CUSTOM ERROR CLASSES

class NoGoodClassifiersError(ValueError):
    def __init__(self, value=""):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class ClassifierError(RuntimeError):
    def __init__(self, value=""):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)


class IdentificationTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, target_classifier, parent_branch_name=None):
        self.target_classifier = target_classifier
        self._parent_branch_name = parent_branch_name
        self._classification = None #value, if leaf node
        self._classifier = None #Classifier, if tree continues
        self._children = {} #dict mapping feature to node, if tree continues
        self._data = [] #only used temporarily for printing with data

    def get_parent_branch_name(self):
        return self._parent_branch_name if self._parent_branch_name else "(Root node: no parent branch)"

    def is_leaf(self):
        return not self._classifier

    def set_node_classification(self, classification):
        self._classification = classification
        if self._classifier:
            print("Warning: Setting the classification", classification, "converts this node from a subtree to a leaf, overwriting its previous classifier:", self._classifier)
            self._classifier = None
            self._children = {}
        return self

    def get_node_classification(self):
        return self._classification

    def set_classifier_and_expand(self, classifier, features):
        if classifier is None:
            raise TypeError("Cannot set classifier to None")
        if not isinstance_Classifier(classifier):
            raise TypeError("classifier must be Classifier-type object: " + str(classifier))
        self._classifier = classifier

        try:
            self._children = {feature:IdentificationTreeNode(self.target_classifier, parent_branch_name=str(feature))
                              for feature in features}
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError("Expected list of feature names, got: " + str(features))
        if len(self._children) == 1:
            print("Warning: The classifier", classifier.name, "has only one relevant feature, which means it's not a useful test!")
        if self._classification:
            print("Warning: Setting the classifier", classifier.name, "converts this node from a leaf to a subtree, overwriting its previous classification:", self._classification)
            self._classification = None
        return self

    def get_classifier(self):
        return self._classifier

    def apply_classifier(self, point):
        if self._classifier is None:
            raise ClassifierError("Cannot apply classifier at leaf node")
        return self._children[self._classifier.classify(point)]

    def get_branches(self):
        return self._children

    def copy(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def print_with_data(self, data):
        tree = self.copy()
        tree._assign_data(data)
        print(tree.__str__(with_data=True))

    def _assign_data(self, data):
        if not self._classifier:
            self._data = deepcopy(data)
            return self
        try:
            pairs = list(self._soc(data, self._classifier).items())
        except KeyError: #one of the points is missing a feature
            raise ClassifierError("One or more points cannot be classified by " + str(self._classifier))

        for (feature, branch_data) in pairs:
            if feature in self._children:
                self._children[feature]._assign_data(branch_data)
            else: #feature branch doesn't exist
                self._data.extend(branch_data)
        return self

    _ssc=lambda self,c,d:self.set_classifier_and_expand(c,self._soc(d,c))
    _soc=lambda self,d,c:reduce(lambda b,p:b.__setitem__(c.classify(p),b.get(c.classify(p),[])+[p]) or b,d,{})

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.target_classifier == other.target_classifier
                    and self._parent_branch_name == other._parent_branch_name
                    and self._classification == other._classification
                    and self._classifier == other._classifier
                    and self._children == other._children
                    and self._data == other._data)
        except:
            return False

    def __str__(self, indent=0, with_data=False):
        newline = os.linesep
        ret = ''
        if indent == 0:
            ret += (newline + "IdentificationTreeNode classifying by "
                    + self.target_classifier.name + ":" + newline)
        ret += "    "*indent + (self._parent_branch_name + ": " if self._parent_branch_name else '')
        if self._classifier:
            ret += self._classifier.name
            if with_data and self._data:
                ret += self._render_points()
            for (feature, node) in sorted(self._children.items()):
                ret += newline + node.__str__(indent+1, with_data)
        else: #leaf
            ret += str(self._classification)
            if with_data and self._data:
                ret += self._render_points()
        return ret

    def _render_points(self):
        ret = ' ('
        first_point = True
        for point in self._data:
            if first_point:
                first_point = False
            else:
                ret += ', '
            ret += str(point.get("name","datapoint")) + ": "
            try:
                ret += str(self.target_classifier.classify(point))
            except ClassifierError:
                ret += '(unknown)'
        ret += ')'
        return ret


################################################################################
############################# k-NEAREST NEIGHBORS ##############################
################################################################################

class Point(object):
    """A Point has a name and a list or tuple of coordinates, and optionally a
    classification, and/or alpha value."""
    def __init__(self, coords, classification=None, name=None):
        self.name = name
        self.coords = coords
        self.classification = classification

    def copy(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def __getitem__(self, i): # make Point iterable
        return self.coords[i]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return (self.coords == other.coords
                    and self.classification == other.classification)
        except:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        ret = "Point(" + str(self.coords)
        if self.classification:
            ret += ", " + str(self.classification)
        if self.name:
            ret += ", name=" + str(self.name)
        ret += ")"
        return ret

    __repr__ = __str__


################################################################################
############################### OTHER FUNCTIONS ################################
################################################################################

def is_class_instance(obj, class_name):
    return hasattr(obj, '__class__') and obj.__class__.__name__ == class_name

def isinstance_Classifier(obj):
    return is_class_instance(obj, 'Classifier')

def isinstance_IdentificationTreeNode(obj):
    return is_class_instance(obj, 'IdentificationTreeNode')

def isinstance_Point(obj):
    return is_class_instance(obj, 'Point')

#id_tree
from api import *
import math
log2 = lambda x: math.log(x, 2)
INF = float('inf')
import pandas as pd


def id_tree_classify_point(point, id_tree):
    if id_tree.is_leaf():
        return id_tree.get_node_classification()
    else:
        new_tree = id_tree.apply_classifier(point)
        get_point = id_tree_classify_point(point, new_tree)
    return get_point

def split_on_classifier(data, classifier):
    """Given a set of data (as a list of points) and a Classifier object, uses
    the classifier to partition the data.  Returns a dict mapping each feature
    values to a list of points that have that value."""
    #Dictionary which will contain the data after classification.
    class_dict = {}
    #Iterating through all the points in data
    for i in range(len(data)):
        get_value = classifier.classify(data[i])
        if get_value not in class_dict:
            class_dict[get_value] = [data[i]]
        else:
            class_dict[get_value].append(data[i])
    return class_dict


def branch_disorder(data, target_classifier):
    """Given a list of points representing a single branch and a Classifier
    for determining the true classification of each point, computes and returns
    the disorder of the branch."""
    #Getting data after classification based on the target_classifier
    class_dict = split_on_classifier(data, target_classifier)
    if (len(class_dict) == 1):
        #Homogenous condition
        return 0
    else:
        disorder = 0
        for i in class_dict:
            get_len = len(class_dict[i])
            p_term = get_len/ float(len(data))
            disorder += (-1) * p_term * log2(p_term)
        return disorder

def average_test_disorder(data, test_classifier, target_classifier):
    """Given a list of points, a feature-test Classifier, and a Classifier
    for determining the true classification of each point, computes and returns
    the disorder of the feature-test stump."""
    average_disorder = 0.0
    #Getting all the branches after applying test_classifer
    get_branches = split_on_classifier(data, test_classifier)
    #Iterating through the branches
    for i in get_branches:
        disorder = branch_disorder(get_branches[i], target_classifier)
        average_disorder += disorder * (len(get_branches[i])/ float(len(data)))
    return average_disorder

#### CONSTRUCTING AN ID TREE

def find_best_classifier(data, possible_classifiers, target_classifier):
    """Given a list of points, a list of possible Classifiers to use as tests,
    and a Classifier for determining the true classification of each point,
    finds and returns the classifier with the lowest disorder.  Breaks ties by
    preferring classifiers that appear earlier in the list.  If the best
    classifier has only one branch, raises NoGoodClassifiersError."""

    #Base values to start with
    best_classifier = average_test_disorder(data, possible_classifiers[0], target_classifier)
    store_classifier = possible_classifiers[0]

    #Iterating over the list of possible classifiers
    for i in range(len(possible_classifiers)):
        avg_disorder = average_test_disorder(data, possible_classifiers[i], target_classifier)
        if avg_disorder < best_classifier:
            best_classifier = avg_disorder
            store_classifier = possible_classifiers[i]

    get_branches = split_on_classifier(data, store_classifier)
    if len(get_branches)==1:
        #Only 1 branch present
        raise NoGoodClassifiersError
    else:
        return store_classifier



def construct_greedy_id_tree(data, possible_classifiers, target_classifier, id_tree_node=None):
    """Given a list of points, a list of possible Classifiers to use as tests,
    a Classifier for determining the true classification of each point, and
    optionally a partially completed ID tree, returns a completed ID tree by
    adding classifiers and classifications until either perfect classification
    has been achieved, or there are no good classifiers left."""
    #print data
    #print "possible", possible_classifiers
    #print "target", target_classifier
    if id_tree_node == None:
        #Creating a new tree
        id_tree_node = IdentificationTreeNode(target_classifier)
    if branch_disorder(data, target_classifier) == 0:
        id_tree_node.set_node_classification(target_classifier.classify(data[0]))
    else:
        try:
            #Getting the best classifier from the options available
            best_classifier = find_best_classifier(data, possible_classifiers, target_classifier)
            get_branches = split_on_classifier(data, best_classifier)
            id_tree_node = id_tree_node.set_classifier_and_expand(best_classifier, get_branches)
            #possible_classifiers.remove(best_classifier)

            branches = id_tree_node.get_branches()
            for i in branches:
                construct_greedy_id_tree(get_branches[i], possible_classifiers, target_classifier, branches[i])
        except NoGoodClassifiersError:
            pass
    return id_tree_node

possible_classifiers = [feature_test('age'),
feature_test('gender'),
    feature_test('duration'),
    feature_test('Mood')
]

df1 = pd.read_csv("data_form.csv")
#df1 = df1.drop("age", axis=1)
print(df1)
a = []
with open("data_form.csv") as myfile:
    firstline = True
    for line in myfile:
        if firstline:
            mykeys = "".join(line.split()).split(',')
            firstline = False
        else:
            values = "".join(line.split()).split(',')
            a.append({mykeys[n]:values[n] for n in range(0,len(mykeys))})
keys = a[0].keys()

print(keys)
with open('data_clean.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(a)
print(a)
tar = feature_test('genre')



print(construct_greedy_id_tree(a, possible_classifiers, tar))


#book_suggestion

import random
#from out import *
def genre(Mood, age, gender, duration):
print("Hi")
res_0= input("What's your name?")
res_1 = input("How are you, "+str(res_0)+"?")
if res_1 in ("good","fine","ok","nice"):
  print ("Oh nice")
else:
  print("Oh! It's alright")
Mood = input("What is your current mood?")
age = input("What is your age range : 10-12, 12-15,13-14,15-18,18+?")
gender = input("What is your gender?")
duration = input("How long do you want to read : 1week, 2weeks, 3weeks, 3+weeks, 2hours")

def get_book(genre):

    suggestions = []
    genre_to_book = {"Fantasy":["Just me and my babysitter - Mercer Mayer","Just Grandpa and me - Mercer Mayer","Just me and my babysitter - Mercer Mayer",
                            "The new Potty - Mercer Mayer","I was so mad - Mercer Mayer","Just me and my puppy" ,"Just a mess" ,"Me too"
                            ,"The new Baby","Just shopping with mom"],

                    "Encyclopedias":["Brain Power - Paul Mcevoy", "My best books of snakes  Gunzi Chrisitian","MY best books of MOON    Grahame,Ian",
                                    "The book of Planets    Twist,Clint", "Do stars have points?    Melvin", "Young discover series:cells   Discovery Channel"] 
                                ,
                    "Action" : ["The Kane Chronicle:The Throne of Fire s Book 2 Riordan,Rick", 
                    "Zane : ninja of ice    Farshtey, Greg",
                    "Escape from Sentai Mountain Farshtey, Greg",
                    "Percy jackson  Rick Riordan",
                    "The Kane Chronicle:The Throne of Fire s Book 2 Rick Riordan"],
                    "Comic" : ["Double Dork Diaries Russell Rachel Renée",
                               "Dork Dairies    Russell Rachel Renee",
                                "Dork Dairies   Russell Rachel Renée"],
                    "Mystery" : ["Sparkling Cyanide Christie Agatha",
                                 "Poirot's Early Cases: Agatha Christie",
                                "The Name of this Book is Secret    Bosch,Pseudonyuous"],
                    "Biographies" :["All by myself  Mercer Mayer", "D Days  prett bryan",
                                    "Snake Bite Lane Andrew"] }


    if (genre == "Fantasy"):
        suggestions =  [random.sample(genre_to_book["Fantasy"], 3)]

    elif (genre == "Action"):
        suggestions =  [random.sample(genre_to_book["Action"], 3)]

    elif (genre == "Comic"):
        suggestions =  [random.sample(genre_to_book["Comic"], 3)]

    elif (genre == "Mystery"):
        suggestions =  [random.sample(genre_to_book["Mystery"], 3)]

    elif (genre == "Encyclopedias"):
        suggestions =  random.sample(genre_to_book["Encyclopedias"], 3)

    elif (genre == "Biographies"):
        suggestions =  random.sample(genre_to_book["Biographies"], 3)


    return suggestions

print(get_book(genre(Mood, age, gender, duration)))
```

I want the program to not depend on out.py and and run on the information of id tree

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking and that is relatively large amount of code to look over with no specific idea of what to look for. What is ```out.py```? The way I understand the question is that you calculate/generate a data structure with data on books, then write the data to a file. Then later in the program (which is in the same python file?) you ask the user a series of questions and want to use the book data to get a book recommendation. Is that right?

Comment: I have a csv from which i need to fetch data to make an id_tree. After generating that, I need to use the data in the id_tree to get a recommendation. Out.py is basically a set of IF Else statements and the book_suggestion.py is totally dependent on it and not on the id_tree. My sir said that the id_tree is generating rules and is Helping the book suggestion. I took out the id_tree and the code was still working. We are not defining any variable from the id_tree.So my question was how do we connect the id_tree after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of the suggestions works by asking the user for a genre, then looking up a list of book titles in a dictionary using that genre as the key, then randomly selecting one of the titles and printing it. The current implementation also (presumably) constructs a `IdentificationTreeNode` containing recommendations, but then does nothing with it except printing it to the standard output.

The next step would be to not discard the tree, but save it in a variable and use in the recommendation process. Since the class structure is not given, it is not clear how this could be done, but it seems a reasonable assumption that it is possible to provide a keyword (the genre) and receive some collection of objects where each one contains data on a recommendation.

If constructing the `IdentificationTreeNode` is too costly to run on each recommendation request, it is possible to split the construction into its own script file and using python's `pickle` package to save the object in a file that can then be unpickled more quickly in the script performing the recommendations.

Comment: But I have many structures of the node in the above program. Where should I define the variable? Even after the Information is defined how do I extract it in  the book_suggestion.py?

Comment: Seperating the code into their own files is no problem and in fact a good idea. However in the code handling the construction of the tree this is happening in the module scope, which is not a good idea. Instead you can wrap the construction in a function, e.g. ```construct_id_tree``` and instead of printing the tree, return it from within in this function. Then in ```book_suggestion.py``` you can import ```construct_id_tree``` from the other module and use it to get the tree. How it can be used to get a suggestion I don't know. The class of the tree is defined in the API and not given above.

Comment: Hi you can see my api.py in the newly updated code above. I'm just using this code for a project in an Intel workshop and being an 8th grader I just want to run this code for a small amount of data